Auto-reconnect Universal Control
How can I automate reconnecting Universal Control if it ever disconnects?
Is it possible to have a script run occasionally that just executes a hardcoded connect?
Sometimes, rather frequently, UC will lose connection without a notable cause.  It always reconnects right away from Displays, and works fine for a while, then like once every 10-20-30m seems to be disconnected.
I've seen a variety of issues and troubleshooting around UC, and I think the best solution here would be an auto-reconnect, because the connecting and subsequent connection is pretty flawless otherwise.
FYI using latest Sonoma and iPadOS, with a MBP (2019), and IPP (2024).  The mac is hardwired and on WiFi as well, and the iPad is just on WiFi (1yo FIOS router), and everything is on the same Apple account, bluetooth on.
Again, I don't think I need to troubleshoot UC here so much as I could use an auto-reconnect, so I don't have to browse through Settings > Displays... each time.

What is 'Universal Control' vs. 'UA'? Did you mean 'UC' instead of 'UA'? What have you tried? There are many articles under the search term 'macos "universal control" loses connection'

You're right - I meant UC, thank you - corrected!
Yes, I have checked out resources; but I would just like an auto-reconnect, or at least a script I can bind to a key, or click once, to re-activate the kb/mouse UC link to the IPP.
I haven't seen a scripted way to execute that settings action.. Displays > [ + button ] > Link keyboard and mouse [select iPad] --- this is what executes the connect, and you can then control the iPad with your macOS kb/mouse (or control macOS with an iPad's own kb/mouse/trackpad).

So, are you saying you need help writing a script to perform a re-connect? That can probably be done with the Automator app. Have you ever used it?  See the Automator documentation.
